# Nginx redirect with Gunicorn on Django app not working properly

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I've developed a simple Django web application but am currently struggling to set up nginx to properly serve static files.

The app runs correctly with Gunicorn on port **8000**. I'm trying to add static files by accessing the port **8080**.

Unfortunately, I get the following timeout message after a request on port **8080**:

```
nginx_1  | 2020/09/02 12:16:56 [error] 27#27: *5 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://172.18.0.4:8000", host: "0.0.0.0:8080"
```

I believe the error is coming from the **`server: ,`** part of the error message above, but can't seem to figure out how to actually solve it.

Here is my nginx `default.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location /static {
        autoindex off;
        alias /vol/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass app:8000;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Here is the `Dockerfile` of my nginx image:

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1-alpine

COPY /docker/prod/nginx/uwsgi_params /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /vol/static
RUN chmod 755 /vol/static

USER nginx
```

And here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/prod/python/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/workspace:cached
      - static_data:/vol/web
    working_dir: /workspace/src/
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.production
    env_file:
      - ./src/.env
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py init_db && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn --preload --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --log-level debug -w 4 config.wsgi"

  # Serving static files with nginx
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/prod/nginx/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - static_data:/vol/static
      - ./docker/prod/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - app

volumes:
  pgdata:
  static_data:
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated. I've spent like a "bad amount of time" on this :D

Comment: You need to make a network connection between the `nginx` instance and the `app` one.  You have 8000 in `app` mapped out to the parent network and 8080 in `nginx` mapped out to the parent network, but nothing making 8000 from `app` available within `nginx`.

Comment: hmm.. I think I may be wrong.  Try looking at https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ .  You could also try getting a console within the `nginx` instance and try manually connecting to `app` and see what happens.

Comment: ... you may want to some non-standard port numbers on the off chance that 8000 is already somehow in use on the `nginx` machine.

Comment: tried that but it didn't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this isn't a proper answer to this question, but I'll leave it here in case anyone runs into the same issue.

I ended up giving up on nginx entirely and just used [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/index.html) to serve my static files. The configuration was 10x easier and the result seems the same. There are probably some cases for which one is better than the other but for my case it worked great.